# USB mount : space issue

Tags: usb, storage, docker

I added a 256 GB USB stick , mounted in :

> /mnt/mydisk

I setup all my docker to have they files stored in the USB stick:

e.g:

```
docker create --name=transmission \
-v /mnt/mydisk/Download/Deluge/ConfigTransmission:/config \
-v /mnt/mydisk/Download/Deluge/:/downloads \
-v /mnt/mydisk/Download/Deluge/Data:/watch \
-e PGID=1000 -e PUID=1000 \
-e TZ=Europe/Dublin \
-p 9091:9091 -p 51413:51413 \
-p 51413:51413/udp \
lsioarmhf/transmission
```

although it's seems I don't have enough space downloading a light linux iso...

Not sure what's happening

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 234.4G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1  31.5K  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    1 234.4G  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    1     8K  0 part 
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59.5G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  59.2G  0 part /
```

UPDATE:

I think I used this for the mount :

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse 
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/mydisk
```

and I add the device to /etc/fstab (something like UUID=THEUUID /mnt/mydisk xfat defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail 0 0)

although, it's seems the fstab file changed, as nothin is listed any more

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
Binary file /etc/fstab matches
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

When I try to manually mount :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/mydisk
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
```

Comment: It looks your USB stick  is not mounted anywhere. Can you add the commands you used to mount it?

Comment: I updated my post but seems like something went wrong with the fstab folder

Comment: So if I understand when I reboot my USB key wasn't mounted anymore, everything I did was save on the SDCard, what should I do ? I assume I can mount the USB in a another path, copy everything to the Usb then mount the USB in the original path again, not sure how to recovery the fstab file though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a corrupted `/etc/fstab` file, so the mount failed and the data was written on the SD card. To correct the problem execute the following steps.

Replace the content of `/etc/fstab` with the following, using the UUIDs you get from `blkid`

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=6c586e13-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=6c586e13-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

Temporarily mount the USB stick on a different directory e.g. `/mnt/tempUSB`

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/tempUSB
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/tempUSB
```

and move the content from `/mnt/mydisk` to the USB stick

```
mv /mnt/mydisk/* /mnt/tempUSB
```

unmount the stick, disconnect it, and delete the temporary directory

```
sudo umount /mnt/tempUSB
sudo rm /mnt/tempUSB
```

Add the new line to `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=THEUUID /mnt/mydisk xfat defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail 0 0
```

save `/etc/fstab` and check the update was successful

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

the output should have 4 lines, with the filesystems `/proc`, `/boot`, `/`, and `/mnt/mydisk`.
Connect the USB stick and mount it using the content of `/etc/fstab`
`sudo mount -a`
Now you should be able to write on it.

To check if the setup is correct you can write a new file in `/mnt/mydisk`, unmount the stick, connect to another PC and check if the new file is there.

Comment: since good thank you very much, didn't check the USB yet but seems to be mounted anyway , thanks again